# Workbook getting hanged during Excel data writing

Tags: excel, office365, office-js, office-addins, excel-web-addins

We have developed an Excel Javascript plugin using the React framework.

Add-in workflow as follows:

1. Request data from Ui using APIs with some parameters
2. Wait for the response and keep it in local cached
3. Start writing data into an active Excel sheet

Problem:

During the Excel data writing, the Excel workbook got frozen until the data is not written in sheet

My case the maximum amount of data coming from APIs is 5-8K.

Below is the sample code.

```
try {
  var i = 0;
  // these data are coming from APIs
  var allCompanies =[12,32,33,43,45,66,12,32,10,12,21,90];
  allCompanies.forEach(async _company => {
    // calling APIs for each _docs and writing data for that companies
    await fetchData(_company).then(async (responseRows) => {
      await Excel.run(async (context) => {
        let sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
        sheet.load(["name"]);
        await context.sync();
        for (let i = 0; i < responseRows.length; i++) {
          // data operations into Exel sheet
          // creating table, table header, applying Css
          // writting value to each cells
        }
        sheet.getUsedRange().format.autofitColumns();
        sheet.getUsedRange().format.autofitRows();
        await context.sync();
      });
    });
  });
} catch (error) {
  console.log("error on appending data into excel " + error);
}
```

Any solution will be helpful to me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If possible, move context.sync() out of the loop. Calling context.sync() multiple times within a loop can result in decreased performance and increased latency.

[Avoid using the context.sync method in loops](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/correlated-objects-pattern)

Comment: If I move context.sync() out of the loop then whatever data I dump into excel will not saw immediately in excel sheet. So that is the reason why I need to sync sheet for each companyId

Comment: You usually have to split the loop into two loops, with a context.sync in between them. See the article that @Bingo linked to.

Comment: Hi, @RickKirkham I have pushed the array into one variable and removed the loop. but it creating issues with writing 7k rows at the same time. is cause any problem if we add rows 7k at a time?

Comment: Excel cannot read more than 5 MB of data in a given call of context.sync.